# node labels: inherit node color

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible for node labels to "inherit" their parent's color? More specifically, I'm doing this:

```
\node[red, label = {[red]above:label}] {node};
```

but I want to be able to do this:

```
\node[red, label = above:label] {node};
```

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}    
    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}    
    \node[red, label = above:label] at (-2, 0) {node};    
    \node[red, label = {[red]above:label}] at (2, 0) {node};    
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

which produces [image: latex output]

Comment: I think it's not possible, labels are independent nodes. You can use `every node/.style` but this affect all nodes.

Comment: There is also `every label/.style`.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for...